# check exist file before upload multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I am using Multer for upload files using Nodejs. Problem is that I cannot verify exist file on server before it deliver to server.

I will check `original name, mime type` and `file size` to make sure it is same.

```
fileFilter: async function (req, file, callback) {
   //but file here return only `original name` and `mime type`. 
}
```

The files are sent to server successfully, multer return in `req.files` but files uploaded. It is not middleware anymore.